# Targeting with VS 2008 after installing SP1 of .NET 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, installation

How do I target .NET 3.5 alone after installing SP1 in VS2008?  This is because VS 2008 lists only .NET 3.5, .NET 3.0 & .NET 2.0 and does not specifically show .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot specify SP1, only different versions of the framework. It does make sense, otherwise you could have a lot of problems with an application specifically compiled for a given SP. You can also have problems with the current situation, but I think it's less headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you reference SP1 assemblies, it should automatically target SP1.